Set the same 'Produces' response for all Minimal API endpoints
in .NET 8, in a project with a minimal API, is it possible to set status codes, for example, 401 Unauthorized, on all endpoints with a single call to a method, for example:
app.MapGroup("test").Produces(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized);

Or do I have to do it for each endpoint like this:
app.MapGet("....", () => "Hello World!").Produces(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized);

Thanks

This extension method simply does not exist at the group level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.openapiroutehandlerbuilderextensions.produces?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I know it doesn't exist, in fact my question is to understand if there is a similar method or something to do it automatically on all endpoints

Gotcha, it is likely possible but you will need to take a look at the current extension method and essentially duplicate the logic but iterate for an entire group


In .NET 8, in a project with a minimal API, is it possible to set
status codes, for example, 401 Unauthorized, on all endpoints with a
single call to a method

Well, based on your scenario and description it can be implemented using  custom middleware or an extension method. Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to apply Produces globally to all endpoints directly.
However, if you look at the the OpenApiRouteHandlerBuilderExtensions where Produces methods belongs to. Which explains, produce attribute is used to specify the content types and other attributes the API can generate, not merely the status codes. As you can see below:

So while working on Produces extension method, be sure about other content type as well.
Now let's have a look how we could generate status code along with other attributes for Produce using Middlware.
Using Middleware:
Let's write a middleware where we would set the status code globally to any http incoming request.
public class StatusCodeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly int _statusCode;

    public StatusCodeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, int statusCode)
    {
        _next = next;
        _statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = _statusCode;
        await _next(context);
    }
}

Now use above middlware to set status code to all endpoint we have:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();


app.MapGet("/Test1", () => "Hello from Test1!");
app.MapGet("/Test2", () => "Hello from Test2!");
app.UseMiddleware<StatusCodeMiddleware>(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized);

app.Run();

Output:

Note: Please have a look at this official document for further reference.

Thanks for the answer, but the way you structured it I would always get 401 which is not correct behavior I think.

What's the behavior you are expecting? Could you please describe what you are looking for.

For example, when I set Produces on an API that value is written to the OpenAPI doc and read by Swagger and I automatically have the doc created.

I'm afraid we could achieve this way. However, you could have a try.
